# Solr: how to turn down logging

Tags: java, logging, solr, slf4j

OK, so I'm *thrilled* with **Solr**, but I can't seem to figure out how to turn down the logging level so that it will actually run acceptably fast when I do a huge import run.

I'm not even sure which logging framework it's using (because, you know, **java.util.logging**, **log4j** and **commons-logging** *weren't enough*, we needed to add **slf4j** to the mix!) OK sorry, had to let that minor rant slip.  :-)

So I have `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` configured with:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
org.apache.solr.core=WARN
org.apache.solr.update.processor=WARN
```

And then for good measure I have `src/main/resources/logging.properties` configured with:

```
.level = WARNING

com.gwtstore.level=ALL
com.appgravity.level=ALL
org.apache.solr.core.level=WARNING
org.apache.solr.update.processor.level=WARNING
```

And yet somehow, I am still seeing tons of the following:

```
INFO: {add=[-7757828706308755634]} 0 0
Feb 21, 2011 6:12:23 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=null path=/update params={} status=0 QTime=0
```

Here's my classpath:

```
src/test/resources
src/test/java
src/main/resources
src/main/java
idea_rt.jar
junit-rt.jar
deploy.jar
dt.jar
javaws.jar
jce.jar
jconsole.jar
management-agent.jar
plugin.jar
sa-jdi.jar
alt-rt.jar
charsets.jar
classes.jar
jsse.jar
ui.jar
apple_provider.jar
dnsns.jar
localedata.jar
sunjce_provider.jar
sunpkcs11.jar
test-classes
classes
junit-4.8.2.jar
gwt-user-2.1.1.jar
gwt-servlet-2.1.1.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
weld-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
jta-1.1.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
hibernate-c3p0-3.3.1.GA.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
cdi-api-1.0.jar
jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.jar
jsr250-api-1.0.jar
lucene-core-2.9.1.jar
lucene-snowball-2.9.1.jar
mongo-java-driver-2.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
proxytoys-1.0.jar
quartz-1.8.4.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-codec-1.2.jar
nekohtml-1.9.7.jar
xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
gwtquickstarter.jar
solr-solrj-1.4.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
solr-core-1.4.1.jar
lucene-analyzers-2.9.3.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.9.3.jar
lucene-memory-2.9.3.jar
lucene-queries-2.9.3.jar
lucene-misc-2.9.3.jar
lucene-spellchecker-2.9.3.jar
solr-commons-csv-1.4.1.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
morphia-0.98s10.jar
androidmarketapi-0.5.jar
openid4java-0.9.5.jar
```

Comment: Loved your short rant, I felt the same way after several hours of reading on the web, along with other API's the might be relevant, but turned out not to be.

Comment: Re your rant: it is really Sun's fault for 1) taking far too time to come up with a "standard" solution, 2) producing a "standard" solution that was technically inferior in a number of respects to the existing alternatives, and 3) giving up on the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You need to make sure that the logging properties file is deployed to `.../yourWebapp/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`.
2. If there is a `.../yourWebapp/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` file, this will override the properties file.
3. The location of the Log4j configuration file can also be overridden by system properties.

For more information on how Log4j gets its configuration, look at [this section](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) of the Log4j introduction.

Comment: that was it, adding ".level = WARNING" to the end of my logging.properties and restarting shut off that INFO logging

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking to turn off logging completely from the Solr server , just visit http://(YOUR-IP):8080/solr/admin and navigate to the logging option seen on top list.

On that page , you could find the detailed table for the various logging levels defined for your Solr installation. Either change their parent logger to make them use the logger you are using in your application or turn them off entirely.

Hope this is what you were looking for.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, with one little caveat: "...This is a transient setting good for doing diagnostic work, but does not persist after reboot...." from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging#line-36

Answer (score 4):

Following link discusses how to configure Solr logging properly.

http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Configuring+Logging

If you want to make changes to logging temporarily, then it can done from the Solr admin page. For making changes permanently you will need to add a JDK logging properties file to Solr web application.

For tomcat following are the steps

1. Create the classes directory in the WB_INF foler for solr web application 
   i.e. _%TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR%/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties_
2. Create logging.properties file
3. Add following entries for setting log level (log levels can be set from FINEST to SEVERE for a class or an entire package)

> org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.level = FINEST
>
> org.apache.solr.level = WARNING

Answer (score 1):

Having done this for log4j for SOLR I can tell you it was painful. Log4j doesn't work well with SOLR out the box. Anyway, here is what I did to make SOLR work with slf4j and log4j. If there is an easier way - awesome - do it.

In solr/lib

- Add slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar ( make
  sure versions match to slf4j-api-???
  )
- Remove slf4j-jdk14-1.5.5.jar (important - otherwise log4j doesnt get used)

in resources in your webapp add your log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "/WEB-INF/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" >
  <appender class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender" name="FILE" >
    <param name="file" value="logs/jetty.log" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout" >
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %C{6} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <priority value="error"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, it seems to confirm what I was guessing from other reading. So SLF4J is just an interface, and therefore you can't control it's output directly with switches.  Instead you need to config the underlying logger, BUT you need to figure out which logger that is.  And for Solr (and maybe Jetty) it looks like it's Java's built in JUL, so that's the one to configure by default, OR swap it out for Log4j as you've done. I also think JULI/Tomcat is sometimes used, though I'm not clear if that's the case when run under the default Jetty, or only when you switch to Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

After long trials of placing the word `WARNING` in infinitely many files, it looks like I've finally managed to slow down Tomcat Solr logging. How would that be useful for your situation/environment is completely beyond me, since my brain is full of JAVA configs as of now. I'm writing it down anyway, with the hope of preventing some pain for someone in the future.

I may have completely disabled some logging along the way, so you may need to undo what I'll be describing here when debugging (or e.g. on the development server).

1. Create a file named `logging.properties` in your config folder, e.g. in `/etc/tomcat...` if it doesn't already exist.
2. If `logging.properties` already exists, comment everything out. You may choose not to comment out other lines though, in case you want some logging.
3. Append / insert the following to `logging.properties`:

   ```
   .level = WARNING
   ```
4. Create a file named `setenv.sh` in your `$CATALINA_HOME/bin` folder if it doesn't already exist. (Where is `$CATALINA_HOME`? Generally in `/usr/share/tomcat...` but type
   `ps -ef | grep tomcat`
   and hunt for the string `catalina.home` or something similar in the output to be sure.)
5. Append / insert the following to `setenv.sh`:

   ```
   export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/etc/tomcat.../logging.properties"
   ```
6. Restart Tomcat (e.g. `/etc/init.d/tomcat... restart`, depends on your OS)

(Replace `tomcat...` with your actual version of Tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was written here in the recent versions of Solr, you have the option to configure slow query logging. You set the threshold above which a query will be considered long-running and such queries will be written in a separate log.

To do that add the `slowQueryThresholdMillis` to your `solrconfig.xml` file. For example, to consider each query running above 2 seconds as slow you would put the following to the `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<slowQueryThresholdMillis>1000</slowQueryThresholdMillis>
```